# Taking information from dead iPhone

Tags: iphone, memory

I have an iPhone that is completely dead. Tried to fix it but there was a problem with the internal circuits if I remember well. I thought about selling the iPhone to people that want parts of it (e.g. screen) but I was doubting if they could somehow reach *private* information that was in the iPhone.

Comment: You'd need to tell us the model & iOS to be certain, but the FBI famously spent millions of dollars getting into an old 4S on iOS 6. That loophole is totally closed since iOS 11.4

Comment: @Tetsujin Hmm I don't really remember the iOS but it is iPhone 5 (the regular 5)

Comment: @PichiWuana An iPhone 5c to be precise. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBI%E2%80%93Apple_encryption_dispute

Comment: FBI paid somewhat over  a million dollars.  The FBI didn't know how the hack worked.  They were provided hardware/software for the hack under the condition they didn't try to  hack the provided hardware or software. You can hack other people's stuff but not our stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reality is that anyone who repairs the phone, and in this case it sounds like it has a logic board issue, will have full access to the phone if it wasn't protected by a passcode. A lot of micro-soldering repairs can be surprisingly straightforward.

In practice however, an iPhone 5 doesn't have much value as a phone so it will most likely serve as a donor device for repairing other phones. If the data on the phone is THAT sensitive to you, then you should consider selling it minus the logic board or see if it can be repaired so that it can be properly wiped clean.

Comment: It had password